# For loop to get rowmeans of each 8 columns in a large dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a large data.frame with 8 columns per sample with 200 samples. I need to get row-means of each 8.

rowMeans(mat[j,1:8]), rowMeans(mat[j,9:16]), rowMeans(mat[j,17:24])...

rownames are gene names.
I used the following:

```
for(j in 1:nrow(mat)){
for (i in 1:ncol(mat)/8) {
row_m[j, i]<- rowMeans(mat[j,c(i:i+7)])
}
}
```

Dataframe sample data, here I have shown 9 columns, should get the mean from first 8 (AM) and then repeat for other samples....

dput(head(deconv3[1:9], 20))
structure(list(AM.amplifying.intestine = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AM43.5.epithelial.of.mammary = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.76506, 0, 0, 1406.48, 0, 196.401,
0, 1996.5, 0), AM.epithelium.of.bronchus = c(549.649, 1647.63,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 699.868, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
AM.epithelium.of.intestine = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 572.85,
59.2414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AM.epithelium.of.trachea = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 199.549, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0), AM.kidney.epithelial.cell = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.32926, 0, 0, 333.592, 0), AM.medullary.thymic.epithelial.cell = c(126.847,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63.1822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26.0598,
0, 11.117), AM.myoepithelial.cell = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AK.amplifying.intestine = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("A1BG",
"A2M", "NAT2", "SERPINA3", "AANAT", "ABAT", "ABCA2", "ABCA3",
"ABCB7", "ABCA4", "ABO", "ACACA", "ACADL", "ACADS", "ACADSB",
"ACAT1", "ACLY", "ACR", "ACP1", "ACRV1"), class = "data.frame")

But it does not work. I am wondering if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(mat)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mat, 20))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample_length <- 8
row_m <- matrix(nrow=dim(mat)[1], ncol = ncol(mat)/sample_length)
for (j in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = ncol(mat), by = sample_length)) {
    row_m[j, (sample_length - 1 + i)/sample_length] <- mean(as.numeric(mat[j, i:(i + (sample_length-1))]))
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to repeat row means for several samples. rowMeans(mat[j,1:8]), rowMeans(mat[j,9:16]), rowMeans(mat[j,17:24]) .....

Comment: Hi Isaiah, Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the output is only one column!

Comment: OK, edited to give a matrix. Because there were 9 rows in the post, and your samples are 8 long, I set sample size to 3 (a multiple of 9), so I could test. With your full data set, just set sample_length to 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
row_m <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:(NCOL(mat) %/% 8 + 1), function(i){
  rowMeans(d[, ((1:NCOL(mat) - 1) %/% 8 + 1) == i, drop=F])}))
```